# Labview cannot send command error

Tags: labview, scpi

i'm trying to control keysight instrument. And i constructed a block diagram in Labview. It works at first, but at second time it won't even respond to *IDN? Command. Visa read block gives timeout error.

I tried restarting my computer, and i tried same block diagram , it works. But at second time, it gives same timeout error in visa read block.

I looked at Keysight instrument's screen. It does not show my sent scpi command on scpi command log, that's why visa read block gives timeout error. But i can't understand why i cannot work same block diagram twice Via Labview.

What do you think the problem is?

PS: When i try Keysight Connectoin Expert's Interactive IO, it works, so i think there's a problem on the Labview on my computer.

Comment: Without seeing the code on your block diagram it's anyone's guess why this is happening.  If you are using LabVIEW 2009 or later, I suggest you (a) create a minimal program that demonstrates the problem, (b) save the code on your block diagram as a code snippet (I think this option is in the EDIT menu), and (c) edit your post to add the code snippet PNG file.  Other people who use LabVIEW can then download the code snippet PNG file and use it to recreate your block diagram code on their computer.  It would also be helpful if you state the instrument's model number--e.g., 34401A or whatever.

Comment: (cont.) See also this tutorial regarding VI snippets on NI's website: http://www.ni.com/tutorial/9330/en/

Comment: @JimFischer updating the problem, my problem appears as i close the instrument without closing Labview. i am controlling N5137B RF Signal Generator .

Comment: Check that the timeout value is set to something reasonable. If it's set too low then the read times out before it completes, and until a read is completed the instrument won't accept further commands (unless you reset the interface e.g. PC restart)

Comment: @NMF thanks, i'll look into it. That's a point of view i did not think about

Comment: @JimFischer i miswrote, my instrument is N5173B RF Signal Generator

Comment: As @JimFischer said, you need to share your code. One common pitfall is an incorrect termination character - many Keysight instruments accept queries (ending in '?') with incorrect termination but glitch/hang/error if a non-'?' command is sent. Often Keysight Connection Expert gets the termination right but you may need to modify the VISA properties in LabVIEW. I assume you're using a 82357B GPIB interface or similar?

Answer (score 1):

Some general comments that are better suited to an answer versus multiple small comments (which are discouraged here).

Does your VI check the instrument's present state before the VI sends a new command to the instrument? A common programming error is to send the instrument a command when it is in a runtime state that prevents it from accepting new commands—e.g.,the previous command has not yet completed; an invalid command was sent to the instrument, the instrument did not understand the command, and the instrument is now in an error state, etc.

When a VI sends a command to an instrument, the VI must next ensure the instrument **fully** and **successfully** executes that command before the VI sends the instrument a new command.  This is done by testing the OPERATION COMPLETE bit and the various ERROR bits in the instrument's EVENT STATUS REGISTER (ESR).  Your VI sends the instrument an *ESR? query and the instrument sends back the 8-bit value from its ESR.  Your VI then tests the states of the OPERATION COMPLETE bit and the ERROR bits in that 8-bit return value.
*(NB: Some instruments have a 16-bit ESR. See your instrument's documentation to determine the number of bits and the bit assignments for the ESR in your instrument.)*
*(NB: Set bits in the ESR remain set until (a) they are read via *ESR? whereupon they are cleared (except for the POWER ON bit), or (b) they are cleared by sending the instrument the CLEAR STATUS command, *CLS.)*

See also the OPERATION COMPLETE query *OPC?.
*NB: On page 153 of Keysight's SCPI Command Reference manual for the N5173B (document ID N5180-90057.pdf) you'll find the following statements regarding the *OPC? querry:*

> This query stops any new commands from being processed until the
>   current processing is complete. This command blocks the controller
>   until all operations are complete (i.e. the timeout setting should be
>   longer than the longest sweep).
>
> CAUTION 
>   The *OPC? query is not recommended for checking if a previous command
>   has been completed by the SCPI parser. (e.g. If the *OPC? query is
>   waiting for a sweep or arb generation that is pending, it could
>   potentially hang the *OPC? query for an undefined extended or even
>   indefinite period of time.)

For instruments that perform measurements, research the MESSAGE AVAILABLE (MAV) flag (bit 4) in the STATUS BYTE REGISTER.

If you discover that the instrument is asserting one or more ERROR flags in its ESR, I suggest you save and close your VIs, close the LabVIEW application, and then use instead a VISA test panel within NI's Measurement Automation Explorer (NI MAX) program to debug these errors.  For example, use the test panel to send the instrument the exact same command string that your VI sends to the instrument, and then use the test panel to query the instrument's ESR (send *ESR?) to determine if the instrument understood the command string and executed it successfully.
*(NB: [THIS WEBPAGE](http://www.ni.com/getting-started/set-up-hardware/instrument-control/gpib-connect) on NI's website discusses GPIB-connected instruments, but the information is also useful for instruments connected via USB, Ethernet, etc.)*

See section 3.9 "Oops typo" and chapter 4 "Instrument Status" in [Rob Limburg's GPIB tutorial](http://g2pc1.bu.edu/~qzpeng/gpib/manual/GpibProgTut.pdf) (PDF).  *(NB: The subsections in section 3.9 are mislabeled as 3.8.x.)*

By the way, I've written LabVIEW VIs that (while still under development) exhibit the behavior you describe where the VI runs once, but all subsequent attempts to run the VI result in error codes or the VI just hangs.  This suggests that my VI caused an NI service or shared library to become unstable. When this happens, I find I can usually (but not always) regain control by (a) power cycling the instrument, AND (b) logging out and logging back in on the computer I'm using. When a user logs out, the operating system (OS) usually unloads from memory any processes or shared libraries that were loaded into memory during a user's login session. As a result, when I log back in and re-launch LabVIEW, the OS reloads the LabVIEW-related services and shared libraries into memory from disk and I get a fresh start (everything works again).  Every once in a while, however, the logout/login cycle doesn't help and the only resort then is to reboot.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was a very detailed answer, i'll look for solution as your message's guidance